# mySQL query is not running in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed mySQL and MySQL workbench. changed the root password when I opened the mySQL workbench for the first time. I have created a simple table and when I try to query that, I am not able to execute the command. Infact not able to execute any query, including show tables; I am able to query them from terminal. I tried inserting some rows into the table from a simple java code, which I am able to do without issues.

Attached is the screenshot of the issue.

[image: Screenshot showing the query executing for ever]

Kindly let me know if anyone faced this issue and if there is any solution for this. Appreciate your help in this regard. 
Able to execute queries from Terminal.

[image: Queries from Terminal]

Comment: `I am not able to execute the command` ... what happens when you run that `SELECT` statement from Workbench?

Comment: Nothing is happening. No error and no processing. Just next to the query window the editor is showing as if the query is being executed for ever. I tried installing by completely uninstalling the SQL and SQL workbench from my machine couple of times. Still the same issue. I am wondering there could be some setting that I am missing.

Comment: Your Workbench probably has a connection problem, possibly SSL.

Comment: Might be. But I am completely not sure if it is a SSL problem. If it is so, it has to give me the same problem if I execute the queries from Terminal. Suspecting something related to SQL workbench

Comment: I am saying that `Workbench` has a connection problem.  Obviously both Java and the command line can reach the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is old but I've ran into this problem lots of times and just now tried to see what's going on.

It's a bug that's well known and seems to pop up over and over again with new releases (both MySQL Workbench and macOS). [Bug #83658](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83658) is the primary one (and where all the dozens of duplicates are being linked to).

There's a link at the end to [bug #87714](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87714) where the issue itself seems to be unrelated but the reporter (Bob Davenport) fixed it by modifying the source and recompiling. You can find the link inside and I'll post it here for completeness sake. It fixed it the same problem you're having for me:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2fTesDcrHzVRGVFWEdILWpuaEE?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

- My MySQL server started on boot.. in the bug report one of the solutions is to restart your server and workbench.
- Restarting server and workbench worked for me